# Close dropdown when tabbing on next/prev element

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to solve an issue where a dropdown needs to close when I've tabbed to the prev or next **TABBABLE** element in the DOM. I tried using focusout and blur but no success.

Here's the JS fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/89r8sucp/21/

And the code is below.

If you have any more insight, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <p tabindex="0">Start</p>
  <br><br><br>
</div>

<div id="guideNav">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <div aria-controls="guideOpt" aria-selected="true" class="guideCurr" role="menu" tabindex="0">
        <div>Rooms</div>
    </div>
    <ul aria-expanded="true" id="guideOpt" role="menu">
        <li role="link">
            <a href="#" role="menuitem" tabindex="0" title="Room 1">Room 1</a>
        </li>
        <li role="link">
            <a href="#" role="menuitem" tabindex="0" title="Room 2">Room 2</a>
        </li>
      <li role="link">
            <a href="#" role="menuitem" tabindex="0" title="Room 3">Room 3</a>
        </li>
      <li role="link">
            <a href="#" role="menuitem" tabindex="0" title="Room 4">Room 4</a>
        </li>
      <li role="link">
            <a href="#" role="menuitem" tabindex="0" title="Room 5">Room 5</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
 <br><br><br>
  <p tabindex="0">End</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#guideNav .guideCurr {
    width: 178px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#guideNav .guideCurr {
    height: 18px;
    padding: 8px 8px 6px 8px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #444;
    background-color: #fff;
}

#guideNav .guideCurr div {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    width: 153px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: inline-block;
}

#guideNav #guideOpt {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 117px;
    left: 55px;
    width: 194px;
    height: auto;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background: #fff;
    z-index: 2;
    margin: 20px 0;
}

#guideNav #guideOpt li {
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(".guideCurr, #guideOpt li a").on("click focus", function(event) {
      event.stopPropagation();
    $(this).next("#guideOpt").show();
});

$(document).on("click", function() {
    $("#guideOpt").hide();   
});

// Below are codes that didn't not close dropdown
//$('.guideCurr, #guideOpt li a').focusout(function() {
//    $('#guideOpt').hide();
//});

//$(".guideCurr, #guideOpt li a").blur(function(){
//    $('#guideOpt').hide();
//});
```

Answer (score 0):

You used `.focusout` function, it should be `.click` function.

I add this code and it's working.

```
$('a').click(function() {
    $('#guideOpt').hide();
});
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/89r8sucp/23/

```js
$(".guideCurr, #guideOpt li a").on("click focus", function(event) {
      event.stopPropagation();
    $(this).next("#guideOpt").show();
});

$(document).on("click", function() {
    $("#guideOpt").hide();   
});

// Below are codes that didn't not close dropdown
//$('.guideCurr, #guideOpt li a').focusout(function() {
//    $('#guideOpt').hide();
//});

//$(".guideCurr, #guideOpt li a").blur(function(){
//    $('#guideOpt').hide();
//});

$('a').click(function() {
    $('#guideOpt').hide();
});
```

```css
#guideNav .guideCurr {
    width: 178px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#guideNav .guideCurr {
    height: 18px;
    padding: 8px 8px 6px 8px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #444;
    background-color: #fff;
}

#guideNav .guideCurr div {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    width: 153px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: inline-block;
}

#guideNav #guideOpt {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 117px;
    left: 55px;
    width: 194px;
    height: auto;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background: #fff;
    z-index: 2;
    margin: 20px 0;
}

#guideNav #guideOpt li {
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p tabindex="0">Start</p>
  <br><br><br>
</div>

<div id="guideNav">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <div aria-controls="guideOpt" aria-selected="true" class="guideCurr" role="menu" tabindex="0">
        <div>Rooms</div>
    </div>
    <ul aria-expanded="true" id="guideOpt" role="menu">
        <li role="link">
            <a href="#" role="menuitem" tabindex="0" title="Room 1">Room 1</a>
        </li>
        <li role="link">
            <a href="#" role="menuitem" tabindex="0" title="Room 2">Room 2</a>
        </li>
      <li role="link">
            <a href="#" role="menuitem" tabindex="0" title="Room 3">Room 3</a>
        </li>
      <li role="link">
            <a href="#" role="menuitem" tabindex="0" title="Room 4">Room 4</a>
        </li>
      <li role="link">
            <a href="#" role="menuitem" tabindex="0" title="Room 5">Room 5</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
 <br><br><br>
  <p tabindex="0">End</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order for your dropdown to process the loss of focus, each item in the menu, the li links in this case, would need an onblur event.

```
    <div id="guideNav">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <div aria-controls="guideOpt" aria-selected="true" class="guideCurr" role="menu" tabindex="0">
        <div>Rooms</div>
    </div>
    <ul aria-expanded="true" id="guideOpt" role="menu">
        <li role="link">
            <a href="#" role="menuitem" tabindex="0" title="Room 1" onblur="closeMe">Room 1</a>
        </li>
        <li role="link">
            <a href="#" role="menuitem" tabindex="0" title="Room 2" onblur="closeMe">Room 2</a>
        </li>
      <li role="link">
            <a href="#" role="menuitem" tabindex="0" title="Room 3" onblur="closeMe">Room 3</a>
        </li>
      <li role="link">
            <a href="#" role="menuitem" tabindex="0" title="Room 4" onblur="closeMe">Room 4</a>
        </li>
      <li role="link">
            <a href="#" role="menuitem" tabindex="0" title="Room 5" onblur="closeMe">Room 5</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
function closeMe(){
    var dropdown = document.getElementById("guideOpt");
    dropdown.style.display = "none";
}
</script>
```

They would then call the close function to hide the dropdown if they lose focus.
Hope this provides some insight.

Comment: Thanks, Christian. I created a new js fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ykzqpkaL/5/ but it seems it's not working after tabbing through the elements on the page. Am I missing something else?